# Google Drive Files/Spreadsheets REST API: How to avoid delay when tracking file changes?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I have an application where I need to keep local copies of some of my user's Google Spreadsheets, and this copy should be in sync with the Google Drive version. I've been testing two methods of tracking changes to a Google Spreadsheet: **(1)** the file version polling method and **(2)** the [files.watch](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/watch) method.

**1) The file `version` polling method**

In this method, whenever I need the most recent version of a Spreadsheet (for instance, when the user wants to download the file from my application), I retrieve the file version from Google using:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/FILE_ID?fields=version
```

If the version is greater than the version I have stored on my end, I know that changes have been made and the file on my end is outdated. So I download the file and update my copy.

The problem is that it takes a while for the file `version` number to be updated on Google's end. Ideally, after editing a Google Spreadsheet cell, my application should be able to detect this change within less than 10 seconds. However, after editing a cell and seeing the **Saved to Drive** confirmation at the top, sometimes it takes seconds, other times it takes minutes before the version number gets updated, so it is very inconsistent.

Aside from the version number, I've also tried polling the `modifiedTime` value to see if it changed sooner, but it didn't. So I tried another method.

**2) The [files.watch](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/watch) method**

In this method, I keep track of the file changes by registering a webhook to receive change notifications from Google:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/FILE_ID/watch
```

Whenever I receive a change notification, I know that I need to update my local copy.

Unfortunately, the change notifications also don't happen as quick as I would like. It also has very inconsistent delays: sometimes taking a few seconds, sometimes taking more than a minute.

**UPDATE (3) The 'always export' method? Never cache method?**

To complicate matters, it seems that even if I ignore my local copy and always try to download the latest version of the file directly from Google, the downloaded file will not necessarily be the absolute latest version that the user sees on the Spreadsheets editor. I tried that using

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/FILE_ID/export?mimeType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

but it would often return the outdated version, and sometimes would only return the latest version after a few minutes.

Is there something else that I can try? The above methods use the Google Drive Files API, but if there is a way to detect changes sooner using the Google Spreadsheets API, I would like to know.

Comment: Have you review the option of using the [revision.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list)?

Comment: The documentation says that "revisions for Google Docs, Sheets, and Slides can't be downloaded" (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-revisions#list-revisions), so even if I retrieved the "revision.list" and saw that a new revision was available, I would not be able to download it, at least not with "files.export", which is the only method I know of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. How to detect file changes as soon as possible?

After a file change (in my case, a change in a Google Spreadsheet), the `version` does not get updated immediately, and when you watch for file changes with the [files.watch](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/watch) API you will also not get a notification immediately.

What *does* get updated immediately is the list of revisions of the file, which can be retrieved with the [revisions.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list) API:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/FILE_ID/revisions
```

This returns a list of all revisions of the file `FILE_ID`. The last item in the list is the most recent revision (the "head" revision). In order to know if a file has changed, I retrieve this list. If the `id` of head revision is different from the `id` stored in my end, it means that my local copy is outdated, so I have to update the file and its revision `id`.

**However**, if you call [files.export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export), the file version returned will not necessarily be the absolute most recent version (e.g., the Google Sheet you are seeing in your browser). And in the case of Google editor documents, it is not possible to retrieve the most recent revision using the [revisions.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/get) API. What can you do then?

## 2. How to retrieve the most recent revision of a Google Sheet?

(I bet it works for other Google editor documents as well).

Before calling [files.export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export), you have to "touch" the file using the [files.update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update) API, updating its `modifiedTime`:

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId
  {
    "modifiedTime": "TIMESTAMP"
  }
```

Where `TIMESTAMP` is a date with the format `2022-04-16T22:00:00Z`.

For some reason, touching the file like this "forces" Google to return the head revision of the file the next time you call [files.export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export):

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/FILE_ID/export?mimeType=MIMETYPE
```

In my case, `MIMETYPE` is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`.

That's it. So far, this has been working for me.

Comment: I'm also encountering these very inconsistent delays, sometimes ~1 second, sometimes several minutes! Did you ever solve this in a more satisfactory way? It would be really good to be able to avoid polling.

Comment: I've been using the same method described above for a year now. I don't like it either, but it is still the only working solution that I know of.